# Running F# in CoreCLR

Tags: c#, f#, coreclr

I compiled [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) and [CoreFX](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) as described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/windows-instructions.md). Basically that works and I can compile and run C# code targeting CoreCLR.
The next step was to try compiling and running F# code. So I added [FSharp.Core 3.1.2.1](http://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core/) to the project and compiled a sample application using the following command:

```
fsc ^
--noframework ^
--targetprofile:netcore ^
/r:packages\System.Runtime.4.0.20-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Runtime.dll ^
/r:packages\System.Reflection.4.0.10-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Reflection.dll ^
/r:packages\System.Collections.4.0.10-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Collections.dll ^
/r:packages\System.Diagnostics.Debug.4.0.10-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll ^
/r:packages\System.IO.FileSystem.4.0.0-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.IO.FileSystem.dll ^
/r:packages\System.Linq.Expressions.4.0.10-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Linq.Expressions.dll ^
/r:packages\System.Console.4.0.0-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Console.dll ^
/r:packages\System.Runtime.Extensions.4.0.10-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll ^
/r:packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.4.0.20-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll ^
/r:packages\System.Text.Encoding.4.0.10-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Text.Encoding.dll ^
/r:packages\System.Text.RegularExpressions.4.0.10-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll ^
/r:packages\System.Threading.Overlapped.4.0.0-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll ^
/r:packages\System.Threading.ThreadPool.4.0.10-beta-22703\lib\contract\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll ^
/r:packages\FSharp.Core.3.1.2.1\lib\portable-net45+netcore45+MonoAndroid1+MonoTouch1\FSharp.Core.dll ^
/out:runtime\HelloWorld.exe HelloWorld.fs
```

As you can see I built against [Profile7](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html) of FSharp.Core.
When I run the application the statement `let test = sprintf "Hello, world"` fails with the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl.PrintfBuilderStack..ctor()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl.PrintfBuilder`3..ctor()
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl.Cache`4.generate(String fmt)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl.f@4277-43[T,TState,TResidue,TResult](String key, Unit unitVar0)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl.Cache`4.get(String key)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfImpl.Cache`4.Get(PrintfFormat`4 key)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule.PrintFormatToStringThen[TResult,T](FSharpFunc`2 continutation, PrintfFormat`4 format)
   at HelloWorld.main(String[] args)
```

I also discussed this [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/issues/405) but I couldn't figure out what I am doing wrong.
Did I include a wrong version of FSharp.Core? Profile7 [should work](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/973#issuecomment-75852041).

Comment: It is just a "file not found" error.  It's been a couple of months since I looked at it but back then only mscorlib.dll was supported and everything else was //todo.  So this is not surprising.  You're too early trying this.

Comment: What do you mean by "only mscorlib.dll was supported"? Do you mean it's too early to use F# with this or too early to try CoreCLR in general?

Comment: I think he means that not all the core libraries are currently supported and you'll just have to wait until they are ported over.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At this time of writing (April 2015), F# has not yet been ported to fully support CoreCLR / CoreFX.

[CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) and [CoreFX](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) are currently undergoing a lot of changes and improvements while development proceeds. The churn will decrease and stability improve rapidly in the coming months, but building anything substantial on CoreCLR/FX at this time will be akin to building a skyscraper on quicksand.

Mono v.next, which is currently used to build and run F# on [LI|U]N[U|I]X, is also undergoing a lot of change as it replaces large chunks of the Mono platform and Framework with assemblies and code from CoreCLR and CoreFX.

You might want to track [Visual F# issue #387](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/387) for progress.

You may also want to track [Visual F# issue #336](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/336) which discusses supporting F# on CoreCLR for x-plat work.

### Update1:

Now that F# 4.0 is shipped, the team are working on a bunch of new work: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/563

Key among those work items is adding CoreCLR support to F#:  https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/499.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarification. I'm looking forward to this.