# How to run a Websharper project using .Net Core and Kestrel from OSX or Linux?

Tags: .net-core, f#, kestrel-http-server, websharper

I'm trying to run a basic Websharper project right from the console using kestrel minimal server, there is a total lack of documentation. I ran the web project using XSP but I want to test it with the new runtime.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29798696/running-f-in-coreclr